# Get Property from XML response sended by Web Service

Tags: android, xml, web-services, ksoap2

Accessing web service by Android application I usually use the Ksoap2 library and the code:

```
  response.getProperty("field")
```

where "field" is the element name of XML, and response is the soapObject in which I have "captured" the WS answer.
The typical XML associate to this answer is:

```
   <registry> 
     <cf>issjdeodk1292983ls</cf> 
     <name>John</name> 
     <surname>Doe</surname> 
     <sex>M</sex>
     <message>a simple optional message</message>
   </registry>
```

In this case when I try to access the field "message" there are no problems:

```
  response.getProperty("message")
```

returns exactly the string "a simple optional message"

But my web service, if the message is not found (server side) return the following XML file

```
   <registry> 
     <cf>issjdeodk1292983ls</cf> 
     <name>John</name> 
     <surname>Doe</surname> 
     <sex>M</sex>
   </registry>
```

that is, the same previous XML without  tag.
In this case if I use the code:
       response.getProperty("message")

an error occurs. 
Can I use a mechanism for getting the property only if  exists?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which library you use but when using xmlpullparser you can lookup if there is a tag like that by

```
if (parser.getName() == "message") { ....
```